# Why does iframe flicker when changing width?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have Google Chrome extension that is added iframe to the page and then I load the micro frontend in that Iframe. I have functionality to display LHS panel inside micro fronted app and for that I need to change width of iframe but when I change width the iframe flickers.

Why does iframe flicker when changing width? And how can I fix it?

I have tried different options how to change iframe width, but without success. so when iframe has 100% width and when I change parent element width to fixed width (e.g 600px) iframe flickers.

https://monosnap.com/file/8c8WxMPQa3NCqb4sU80oTQXSF9H2jd

Comment: There's no dedicated setting for this, so it must be either a bug in Chrome or in your code. Try debugging in devtools -> Performance with screenshots recording enabled and then look at the code before the flicker.

Comment: Hey mate, I ran performance recording, content inside iframe is hidden and then shown or iframe is hidden and then shown...

Comment: Well you need to look at the code that runs in this time span.

Answer (score 0):

This is nearly always caused by having overly complex CSS that takes too long to rerender.  The other cause is having slow JS triggered when the content resizes.

If you have JS being called multiple times, then using the `debounce()` function from the lodash library often helps.

I’m afraid you question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow. I would suggest narrowing it down to what is causing the slow down and then asking a more specific question if you still need help.